# Hacked by blackwave

Tags: linux

The last week my website got hacked by blackwave and im really confused about it , the confusing is that i can log in to my wordpress dashboard but without any permissions , i cant do nothing about it , like someone missed or changed the wp-config.php or wp-login.php or i dont know please i really need the file that i have to edit and get the real php script of wp-config and wp-login , can you guys help me ? Thanks alot i really appreciate it if u helped me. this is my website : http://brand-samara.ru

Comment: Trying to fix already compromised WordPress is useless. Restore from backup and patch for the original vulnerability.

Comment: Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

From link you provided, it looks like you're being hacked by [WSO malware](http://www.stratigery.com/phparasites/wso.html).

You may attempt to remove malware with tools like [Linux Malware Detect](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) or [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) or [ClamAV with extended, unofficial signatures](https://github.com/extremeshok/clamav-unofficial-sigs), and you will have more or less success, **but only way to be certain** the malware is gone is to wipe everything and restore from backup. I hope you have backup. You may want to read this very informative [Q&a about your problem - how to deal with compromised server](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server). Good luck.